# predicate solve/2 its first argument is non-empty list ,second argument is list consisting of zero or more appended copies of the first argument

Tags: prolog

```
solve([],[]).
solve([H|T] ,L2) :-
     solve(T,L2).
solve(L1,[H,H|T1]) :-
     solve(L1,T1).
```

expected values

```
solve([a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b], X).

X = [] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;

X = [a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b] ? ;
```

this goes on till infinity

actual output

```
X = [] ? ;

X = [A,A] ? ;

X = [A,A,B,B] ? ;

X = [A,A,B,B,C,C] ? ;

X = [A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D] ? ;

X = [A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D,E,E] ? ;

X = [A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D,E,E,F,F] ?
```

im not sure why this is happening im not able to get it multiply by the initial first argument length its starting from 0 and up in 2s any help on getting the first arguement outputted 0 or more times?

Comment: What query did you enter that gives your "actual output"?

Answer (score 1):

We will use the `append/3` : https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3

```
solve(L1, []). 
solve(L1, L2) :- solve(L1, L3), append(L1, L3, L2).
```

The empty list is 0 copies of the first argument.

If `L3` is `n` copies of `L1`, and `L2` is `L1` concatenated with `L3`, then `L2` is `n+1` copies of `L1`.

**Edit**

To make searching for solutions in the first argument possible, we make two changes:

1. Guarantee the first argument has at least 1 element.
2. Put the `append` requirement first.

The code is now as follows:

```
solve([_|_], []). 
solve([H|L1], L2) :- append([H|L1], L3, L2), solve([H|L1], L3).
```

Comment: @dave I have now fixed this and edited my answer